# How do i rename files in command prompt using the same scheme as windows explorer [file name] [number]?

Tags: command-prompt

i have a drive full of samsung smart tv recall memories 4.75 kbps amr files, and i don't want the viewers (youtube) to find that out until an upcoming video is released so i want to rename every last file to music, but every time i try to do that, it either says A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found. or The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error. and my command line is ren *.*/*.amr music.amr. music ({0}).amr gives me the "the syntax of the command is incorrect" error. so what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: "what am I doing wrong here?" is expecting far too much of command prompt to understand `{0}` (where is that syntax from?). If you want to count, you'll need a batch file with environment variables and `set /A` (see `set /?` for details), and good luck doing the string replace in the name, possible but not trivial. What was your PowerShell code? I just copied a directory with 220 files, and PowerShell 5.1 renames them all in 51 milliseconds, and that directory is not even on an SSD, still spinning disk.

Comment: my powershell code is ls | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("music ({0}).amr" -f $nr++)}